# How to databind to parent property in custom control

Tags: wpf

I have 2 custom controls: 1 for design wrap control and the second is custom richtextbox control.
the richtextbox is loading data from a file, Now for every Run control inside i want check his parent (Span control) 's field of FontFamily, if the value is "Symbol", so do someting, but i see that the databinding isn't fired, how to correct it?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HelpCtrl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HelpCtrl}">
                <Grid>

                    <Grid x:Name="gridRichTextBox" Background="Black" Width="350" Height="600">
                        <local:RichTextBoxWithTextProperty                                 
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            x:Name="rtbHelpText"            
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"     
                            Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:HelpCtrl}}}">
                            <local:RichTextBoxWithTextProperty.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>

                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Span}},Path=FontFamily}" Value="Symbol">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </local:RichTextBoxWithTextProperty.Resources>
                        </local:RichTextBoxWithTextProperty>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else because your code works fine.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HelpCtrl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HelpCtrl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="gridRichTextBox">
                        <RichTextBox>
                            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Span}},Path=FontFamily}" Value="Symbol">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </RichTextBox.Resources>
                            <FlowDocument>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Span FontFamily="Tahoma">Some text</Span>
                                    <Span FontFamily="Symbol">Some symbol</Span>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </FlowDocument>
                        </RichTextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Make sure you don't set DataContext of CustomControl in its own class. you have to set it in xaml where it's being used:

```
<local:RichTextBoxWithTextProperty DataContext="{Binding ...}" Text="{Binding Text...}">
```

Comment: You are right! if i delete the binding to dependency property it working.. what's the problem with the binding?

Comment: You mean the <local:RichTextBoxWithTextProperty Text="{...}"> ? My guess is the Text from HelpCtrl is not converted into a Run or Span. so the trigger has no effect.

Comment: You can fill an observable collection of Spans and then bind it to a an ItemsControl in FlowDocument.Paragraph

Comment: The problem is that i need to binding to parent's Text for loading a path from it for loading from a file into richtextbox..i don't sure how to implement your suggest?

Comment: I suggest you first try your method without binding (button click event) I think the problem is with how you set richtextbox's contents.

Answer (score 0):

@Bizz, yes, if i delete the bindings the style of Run is paint as expected.. i tried to fill observable collection of Blocks as:

```
static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(e.NewValue.ToString()));
        RichTextBox r = new RichTextBox();
        r.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        HelpCtrl helpCtrl = d as HelpCtrl;

        ObservableCollection<Block> l = new ObservableCollection<Block>();
        while (r.Document.Blocks.Count > 0)
        {
            var block = r.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock;
            r.Document.Blocks.Remove(block);
            l.Add(block);
        }
        helpCtrl.Blocks = l;
    }



    public ObservableCollection<Block> Blocks
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Block>)GetValue(BlocksProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BlocksProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Blocks.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlocksProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Blocks", typeof(ObservableCollection<Block>), typeof(HelpCtrl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HelpCtrl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HelpCtrl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="gridRichTextBox" Background="Black" Width="350" Height="600">
                        <RichTextBox   
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            x:Name="rtbHelpText"            
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            >
                            <FlowDocument>
                                <FlowDocument.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Span}},Path=FontFamily}" Value="Symbol">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Inlines}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <WrapPanel/>
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </FlowDocument.Resources>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:HelpCtrl}}}"/>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </FlowDocument>
                        </RichTextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but now the style of run is not paint nothing...